# populate a Document template with value of look up from Related entity in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to load a field in the Document Template. Below is my scenario

I have Contracts linked to Opportunity (N:1). There is a contact lookup field in the Opportunity

When I generated the Document Template, I selected all 1:N, N:1 & N:N relations, but I don't get the details of Contact field under new_Opportunity_new_contract (relation)

In the Document Template of Contracts, I need to pull the Contact Name from the lookup field in Opportunity.

Is it possible to get that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to create a **Word** Document Template.

After going to Settings -> Templates -> Document Templates and clicking *New*, you have to select 1.Word Template and 2.Contract, then click *Select Entity*:

[image]

When the relationship selector popup appears select the opportunity to contract relationship that you have created and click *Download Template*:

[image]

A word document will be downloaded to your computer, open it. Then, click in the Developer tab (if it does not show up go to File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon and in the right Select the Developer tab).

Then 1.Click the *XML Mapping Pane* which will open a pane in the right side of your monitor. 2.At the top of the Pane there will be a picklist where you have to pick the option which starts with *urn:microsoft*. 3.Scroll down until you see the relationship you have created between opportunity and contract and expand it:

[image]

Search for a field with the name "yourlookupid" + "name" at the end.
Right click it to add to the form, click *Insert Content Control* and *Plain Text*:

[image]

Finally, go back to Dynamics and upload your word template file by clicking *Upload Template* in the templates view.

**Reminder** don't forget to enable the security roles for your users as well ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did these steps, but i am not able to access the contact details which is in opportunity entity

Comment: Search for the lookup schema name + "name". For example if the lookup you want the name of is *contactid* search for *contactidname*.

Answer (score 1):

I Went through your exact requierement, I have a followup question,
Do you really have to go From Contract--> Opportunity--> and then Contact.
Because when I check in Contract Entity you will find two N:1 Relation from Contract To Contact

1. contract_billingcustomer_contacts
2. contract_customer_contacts

These 2 Relationship will also give you Contact Details information on Document Template.

But if you wish to go from  Contract--> Opportunity--> and then Contact
then this is not possible in Word Template as you are trying to Reach 3rd level of Relationship

Below are few Screenshots from my Word Template Example for Contract

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Even though it is a 3rd level of a relationship as long as it is a N-1 you can access its name, just search for a field with the name lookupname + "name"